# How to install and run graylog2 without root privilege nor write permission to /etc

Tags: ubuntu, graylog2

Following the [current default installation instructions for graylog2](http://support.torch.sh/help/kb/graylog2-server/installing-graylog2-server-v020x-on-nix-systems) it appears as if it assumes the installation is using user `root`.

It seems it assumes freehand access to `/etc` which I don't really like nor think it should be necessary. E.g. upon startup it tries to update a file `/etc/graylog2-server-node-id`.

How can graylog2 be up and running (Ubuntu 13.04 or otherwise) without requiring write access to the entire `/etc`, and in general without requiring any special permissions?

P.S. I think I can manage granting it the port privilege it needs without using root/sudo, so I would rather not assume it really needs to use root permissions only for that...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that was silly. In the configuration file, change `node_id_file = /etc/graylog2-server-node-id` to something else. Hope `root` assumptions won't pop up elsewhere..

Comment: And too bad it doesn't find the default elasticsearch installation out of the box nor come with a sample mongodb connection setup script.